# SQL Server Reporting Service Failed to Initialize the Report Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm running into an issue while trying to launch the SQL Server Reporting Service (SSRS) from my local machine. The error highlights it is unable to open the source file `App_global.asax.pddxk8z6.0.cs` from the `c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\reportserver\RSTempFiles\reporting\0de1224a\5ba1101c\App_global.asax.pddxk8z6.0.cs` directory.

[image]

Here's the full stacktrace for reference:

```
Failed to initialize the AppDomain:ReportServer_SSRS_0

Exception: System.Web.HttpCompileException

Message: (0): error CS1504: Source file 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\reportserver\RSTempFiles\reporting\0de1224a\5ba1101c\App_global.asax.pddxk8z6.0.cs' could not be opened ('Unspecified error ')
```

StackTrace:

```
at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
at System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod()
at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel)
at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel)
at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironmentAndReportErrors(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
```

Please note that `asax` cs files are generated dynamically with a distinct name every single time. Hence, there's no way we can simply create a brand new source file with a similar name and expect that to work. Also, this file currently does not exist in the directory mentioned above. I've tried several approaches in an attempt to resolve this issue so far:

- Delete everything under `RSTempFiles` directory and relaunch the SSRS.
- Give full admin permission to the SSRS directory in case the permissions weren't allowing the application to create the source files.
- Enabled relevant.NET Framework options (.NET Framework 3.5, .NET Framework 4.8 Advanced Services -> ASP NET 4.8 and WCF Services) under 'Turn Windows features on or off'.
- Checked Windows Firewall to ensure it is not blocking anything.
- Repair/Reinstall .NET Framework

Please note there's no Visual Studio project involved. I saw many troubleshooting tips that were related to VS during my research about this issue.

Any tips are welcome at this point!

Comment: Antivirus exclusions?

Comment: I checked the Windows Firewall and Antivirus to see if it blocked anything. There's nothing odd that's been blocked so far.

Answer (score 0):

Not to much information out there on error CS1504 :( , my initial thought was also an acces rights issue, but you already checked that.

Grasping at straws, focussing on the error500: is the Sql Server Reporting Services running/try to restart that one, and try to clear you browser cash?

Sorry i dont have a definite answer for you.

Edit , what url are you using? I have it running locally and its in the format:   http://sql-server-name/reports/browse

another urls to try is :  http://servername/reportserver

Edit 2: also try replacing servername with localhost

Comment: I tried clearing the cache and restarting the sql server, however it did not work. I also tried replacing the servername with localhost like you suggested, but still the same issue. Regarding the url, I have set it up as http://servername/Reporting.